I forgot to tell a journal that the submitted article is actually a condensed version of my MA thesis!
I had asked a journal (let's call it X) if they accept master's thesis for publication, they replied by saying that they don't and I'd have to reformat it as an article to be considered for publication.
I then reformatted my MA thesis and submitted it to journal X. For context, my MA thesis was 100+ pages, whereas the article is half that. After a few days I got a reply saying that it would be better to submit my article to journal Y. So, I just sent the document (article) to journal Y simply texting them for submission. It has been over a month and last week I got a reply from them saying that it is now in blind PR, which, obviously being elated on the progress, I responded with excitement.
Today, talking to my supervisor, who also was happy for me, asked me if I mentioned it to the journal that the article is a condensed version of my thesis. Am I doomed!?
I'm quite anxious now as to what might happen, I feel like a fraud. It is a prestigious humanities journal and I feel like I just really messed up my chance to get published.
Am I overthinking or underthinking this? I'm worried that I might be flagged as a bad academic or something, maybe I'll never be able to publish, or how the journal's editors might react when they find out. Or should I tell them right now, or later, or never, or am I technically plagiarising my own work?

Is your thesis itself published via your university?

My country does have an all-in-one website where thesis and dissertations of students and scholars are available. I searched there for mine, it wasn't there.

Did you cite your previous thesis in the condensed article?

Don't panic. It's probably fine, and in the worst case you won't be blacklisted - you'd just have your paper rejected.
In most fields that I'm aware of, it's quite OK to publish from your thesis - after all, if you have found out something new and interesting then it is good to have it in the published record. (whether it is sufficiently new and interesting is another matter - but that's about what the reviewers say, not whether it was OK to submit it) You do need to write it in the format of a journal article, not just submit the thesis, as you have found out. And fifty pages sounds long, but this does vary by field.
So. I think that ideally you would have mentioned in the cover letter that it was your MA. It's probably fine anyway, but if you want to be clear you could write to the editor of the journal and briefly and concisely explain that it is, that you forgot to say so in the cover letter, and that you hope it is OK.
Honestly I'm not sure that is necessary; I'll be interested to hear others' views there.
Note that it being OK to have submitted does not mean that your work will be accepted; but that's a fact of academic life for all of us! The fact that it has gone to peer review suggests that (a) the editor thought it was worth reviewing, and (b) if it is rejected, you have a good chance of useful feedback.

Thanks! I've drafted a brief and concise email, just in case I have to send it. Waiting to hear more thoughts on the matter :)

@nightcat you probably shouldn't be thinking in terms of "have to send it" but just in terms of "oops, I forgot to mention something I probably should have done, better let them know just in case." It's not worth agonising over the decision - there's an obvious right thing to do and it's unlikely to be a big deal anyway.

@N.Virgo Indeed. Strictly necessary or not, you can never go wrong by telling the truth.

Relax, this is a perfectly solvable problem.  Since your paper it a cut-down version of your Masters thesis, it is appropriate that it should cite that work and state what it is up-front.  That is unlikely to affect peer review of the article.  I recommend that you write to the editor noting that your paper is based on your Masters thesis and you intend to add a citation to your Masters thesis prior to publication.  The editor might decide to pass this information on to the referees, or might just ignore it and let you make this revision later in the process.

Masters theses and dissertations are usually not considered publications per se, even if they are publicly visible. They, for example, do not typically count as a "peer-reviewed publication" in an application, and that despite having gone through a form of peer review (i.e. marking).
You should be fine, but it might be good to check with your supervisor. Sure, reformatting or rewriting it to suit the journal might be necessary, as theses (when well written) are usually in a more didactic or free-flow form than journal articles.

Since it’s a journal in the humanities, it’s probably more likely an MA thesis than an MSc thesis.

@JanusBahsJacquet Changed, thank you!

I'm working on a paper right now that's essentially a write-up of my undergrad thesis, and put this snippet at the front:

\section{Foreword}
The majority of this work was carried out under the auspices of the
primary authors' undergraduate thesis \cite{MyThesisCitation}. This thesis
has never been published and has not been made available publicly by
any institution. The intent is for this paper to distill that work into
a form suitable for publication and should be considered novel despite
the existence of the unpublished thesis. Should the reader wish to
receive a copy of the full thesis, we will happily provide it on
request. It contains significantly more detail as to the construction
and testing of the device than is contained herein.

I wouldn't worry too much, my supervisor said this is probably unnecessary but I wanted belt and braces. If you're really concerned, just email the editor an FYI.
